# Compara sqlsrv_query com texto

Tags: php, sql-server

estou iniciando em PHP junto de SQL Server 2008.

O código abaixo faz uma consulta no banco de dados e exibe o que se foi obtido.

```
<?php
$serverName = "DESKTOP-B8EB4SG\SQLEXPRESS";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"contas", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"123456" );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

//$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (login, senha) VALUES (?, ?)";


$seleciona = "SELECT Login FROM pessoas WHERE UID=3";

// Executa a consulta
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $seleciona);
if ($stmt === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}


if ($stmt == "renato")
echo "Bem-vindo";

// Exibe o resultado
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['Login'].'<br>';
}       


?>
```

[image: Cade o bem-vindo??]

Eu gostaria que quando o nome do Login obtido fosse **renato**, ele exibisse **Bem-vindo**.
Afinal, porque o bem-vindo não aparece? Por acaso precisa de algum tipo de conversão para string/char?

OBS: Eu sei que devem existir infinitas explicações sobre isso, porem não sei exatamente o que pesquisar.

Comment: `$stmt` é um resource e nunca será igual a uma string como `renato`. Não entra naquele if inline.

Comment: O que eu posso fazer?

Comment: Pode fazer `echo 'bem vindo '. $row['Login'].'<br>';`

Comment: Apareceu somente o bem vindo

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer o `if` dentro do `while`:

```
// Exibe o resultado
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    if ($row['Login'] == "renato")
         echo 'Bem-vindo'.'<br>';
    else
         echo $row['Login'].'<br>';
}
```

Dessa forma, ele verifica se é `renato`, caso for, imprime `"Bem-vindo"`, e caso não, imprime o retorno.